# How to Redirect the Console I/O in a already opened file in PERL

Tags: perl, redirect, printing, console

I'm using system() function in PERL to execute commands. I want to redirect the console I/O of this function to a file which is already opened in my PERL script (see below). I know it is not possible to open the same file in PERL as well for re-directing however I need to print everything in a single file (Both my PERL script print statements and re-directed outputs) within the PERL script. Could any one please help me on this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open FPTR, ">Test.txt";
print FPTR "Executing Command1...\n";
system("Time >>Test.txt");

print FPTR "Executing Command2...\n";
system("Date >>Test.txt");

close FPTR;
```

Thanks,

Anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`STDOUT` can be redirected to already open file handle `FPTR`. Going out of `do` block, `STDOUT` is restored back due dynamic scope set by `local`,

```
do {
  local *STDOUT = \*FPTR;
  print `date`;
};
```

From http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html

> A local modifies the listed variables to be local to the enclosing block, file, or eval.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the below piece of code and I'm getting error message, "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

<code>
open FPTR, ">Test.txt";
print FPTR "Executing Command1...\n";
do {
 local *STDOUT = \*FPTR;
 system("Date >>Test.txt");
};

close FPTR;
</code>

Comment: Yes Correct. I'm using win-7.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the backtick operator to execute the command and store it's output in a variable:
`` my $var = `time`; ``

As soon as you have the output stored you can simply append it to your file.

Hope that helps you.